# wordpress - category__not_in not working

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm having a problem getting my query function. I need to run the loop, excluding a particular category.

I'm trying to use `category__not_in`, but is not working at all some.

```
<?php
  $args = array(
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'category__not_in' => array( '44' ),
    'posts_per_page' => 9,
    'paged' => get_query_var('paged')
  );
  $query = new WP_Query( $args );

  query_posts($query);
?>
```

I've already tried:

```
'category__not_in' => array( '44' ),
'category__not_in' => array( 44 ),
'category__not_in' => '44',
'category__not_in' => 44,
```

But nothing works     =(

Comment: as in http://www.billerickson.net/code/wp_query-arguments/ , the right way is `'category__not_in' => array(44)`

Comment: I tested it, but it did not work that way

Comment: Why are you using both `WP_Query()` and `query_posts()`? You shouldn't be using `query_posts()`. You should also be using `'category__not_in' => array( 44 ),`. There's nothing wrong with the query, otherwise. Make sure you're using the proper category ID.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thanks guys, it worked thanks to [@rnevius](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3518452/rnevius)

The problem was in my query, I was using `WP_Query()` and `query_posts()`.

I used how reference the WP Codex: https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query

Below is how my code was at the end:

```
<?php
  $args = array(
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'category__not_in' => array( 44 ),
    'posts_per_page' => 9,
    'paged' => get_query_var('paged')
  );
  $query = new WP_Query( $args );
?>

<?php
  if ( $query->have_posts() ) {
    while ( $query->have_posts() ) {
      $query->the_post();
?>

// code

<?php
    }
  } else {
    // no posts found
  }
  wp_reset_postdata();
?>
```

Answer (score 10):

Try using tax_query instead :

```
<?php
  $args = array(
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'posts_per_page' => 9,
    'paged' => get_query_var('paged'),
    'tax_query' => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => '<YOUR TAXONOMY NAME>',
            'field'    => 'term_id',
            'terms'    => array( 44 ),
            'operator' => 'NOT IN',
        ),
    ),

  );
  $query = new WP_Query( $args );

  query_posts($query);
?>
```

Comment: Not sure why this was downvoted, solved my problem and also allows you to do more complex stuff for filtering your posts, see https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Taxonomy_Parameters

Answer (score 5):

Use `'cat' => '-44'` in your `$args` array:

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'cat' => '-44',
    'posts_per_page' => 9,
    'paged' => get_query_var('paged')
);
```

It's the way recommended in the [WP Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/query_posts#Exclude_Categories_From_Your_Home_Page).

Comment: This is definitely another way of doing it, but still doesn't explain why [`category__not_in`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Category_Parameters) wouldn't be working for the OP.

Comment: There's a closed Github issue about that. They say it's because `category__not_in` is a private query variable, meaning it's [not accessible to logged-out users](https://github.com/WP-API/WP-API/issues/1884)

Comment: It's not being used as a query variable in this situation. That Github issue is about something entirely different (a URL query variable being used in the WP API).

Answer (score 0):

To exclude a category in the search use this:

```
function search_filter($query)
{
if ( !is_admin() && $query->is_main_query() ) {
    if ($query->is_search)
    {
        $taxquery = array(
            array(
                'taxonomy'  => 'category',
                'field'     => 'term_taxonomy_id',
                'terms'     => 244,
                'operator'  => 'NOT IN',
            )
        );
        $query->set( 'tax_query', $taxquery );
    }
}
```

}

add_action('pre_get_posts','search_filter');