# Wordpress- how to use 'category__not_in' in wp_query

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a small problem.
I am trying to retrieve all posts from certain custom post type excluding the posts tagged In category id 78.

I have two posts. 
One tagged as category 78 only and one that is not tagged as category 78. 
I checked in older posts like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36178150/wordpress-category-not-in-not-working) but for me it is not working.
I see all the results.

this is my code:

```
 function data_fetch(){

    $the_query = new WP_Query( array( 'posts_per_page' => -1, 's' => esc_attr( $_POST['keyword'] ), 'post_type' => 'article', 'category__not_in ' => array( 78 ) ) );
    if( $the_query->have_posts() ) :
        while( $the_query->have_posts() ): $the_query->the_post(); ?>

            <h2><a href="<?php echo esc_url( post_permalink() ); ?>"><?php the_title();?></a></h2>

        <?php endwhile;
        wp_reset_postdata();
    endif;

    die();
}
```

This is the post type init query function:

```
    function article_cpt_init() {
    $labels = array(
        'name' => 'פריטי מאגר מידע',
        'singular_name' => 'פריט מאגר מידע',
        'add_new' => 'הוסף פריט מאגר מידע חדש',
        'add_new_item' => 'הוסף פריט מאגר מידע חדש',
        'edit_item' => 'ערוך פריט מאגר מידע',
        'new_item' => 'פריט מאגר מידע חדש',
        'all_items' => 'כל פריטי מאגר מידע',
        'view_item' => 'הצג פריט מאגר מידע',
        'search_items' => 'חפש פריט מאגר מידע',
        'not_found' =>  'לא נמצא פריט מאגר מידע',
        'not_found_in_trash' => 'לא נמצא פריט מאגר מידע בפח',
        'parent_item_colon' => '',
        'menu_name' => 'פריטי מאגר מידע',
    );

    $args = array(
        'labels' => $labels,
        'exclude_from_search' => true,
        'public' => true,
        'publicly_queryable' => true,
        'show_ui' => true,
        'show_in_menu' => true,
        'query_var' => true,
        'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => 'article' ),
        'capability_type' => 'post',
        'has_archive' => true,
        'hierarchical' => false,
        'taxonomies' => array('category', 'audience'),
        'menu_position' => null,
        'supports' => array( 'title', 'excerpt', 'editor' )
    );

    register_post_type( 'article', $args );
}
add_action( 'init', 'article_cpt_init');


/**
 * Register speciality Taxonomט
 */
function register_speciality_taxonomy() {
    $taxonomies = array(
        array(
            'slug'         => 'category',
            'single_name'  => 'נושא',
            'plural_name'  => 'נושאים',
            'post_type'    => 'article',
            'rewrite'      => array( 'slug' => 'נושאים' ),
        ),
        array(
            'slug'         => 'audience',
            'single_name'  => 'קהל יעד',
            'plural_name'  => 'קהלי יעד',
            'post_type'    => 'article',
            'rewrite'      => array( 'slug' => 'קהל יעד' ),
        ),
        array(
            'slug'         => 'tags',
            'single_name'  => 'תגיות',
            'plural_name'  => 'תגיות',
            'post_type'    => 'article',
            'rewrite'      => array( 'slug' => 'תגיות' ),
            'hierarchical' => false,
        )
    );
    foreach( $taxonomies as $taxonomy ) {
        $labels = array(
            'name' => $taxonomy['plural_name'],
            'singular_name' => $taxonomy['single_name'],
            'search_items' =>  'Search ' . $taxonomy['plural_name'],
            'all_items' => 'All ' . $taxonomy['plural_name'],
            'parent_item' => 'Parent ' . $taxonomy['single_name'],
            'parent_item_colon' => 'Parent ' . $taxonomy['single_name'] . ':',
            'edit_item' => 'Edit ' . $taxonomy['single_name'],
            'update_item' => 'Update ' . $taxonomy['single_name'],
            'add_new_item' => 'Add New ' . $taxonomy['single_name'],
            'new_item_name' => 'New ' . $taxonomy['single_name'] . ' Name',
            'menu_name' => $taxonomy['plural_name']
        );

        $rewrite = isset( $taxonomy['rewrite'] ) ? $taxonomy['rewrite'] : array( 'slug' => $taxonomy['slug'] );
        $hierarchical = isset( $taxonomy['hierarchical'] ) ? $taxonomy['hierarchical'] : true;

        register_taxonomy( $taxonomy['slug'], $taxonomy['post_type'], array(
            'hierarchical' => $hierarchical,
            'labels' => $labels,
            'show_ui' => true,
            'query_var' => true,
            'rewrite' => $rewrite,
        ));
    }

}
add_action( 'init', 'register_speciality_taxonomy' );
// Display User IP in WordPress
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: can you specify the post type and the taxonomy type?

Comment: you mean the custom post type init code?

Comment: ok let me see that, i can see that the post type is article but i need the category type ( is this post tagged to default category or assigned to some custom taxonomy?)

Comment: `'category__not_in '` need to be `'category__not_in'` remove extra space  there

Comment: @alive no its 'category__not_in' not 'category_not_in'. Reference: https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Category_Parameters

Comment: @Yamu  yes. but remove extra space between `in` and `'` there. I have edited my comment before you said

Comment: ohh didn't noticed that hehe

Comment: @Yamu I removed the space between the `in` and the `'` still get all the results...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
function data_fetch(){
$args = array( 'posts_per_page' => -1, 
                's' => esc_attr( $_POST['keyword'] ), 
                'post_type' => 'article', 
                'tax_query' => array(
                        array(
                            'taxonomy' => 'audience',
                            'field'    => 'term_id',
                            'terms'    => array( 78 ),
                            'operator' => 'NOT IN',
                        ),
                    ), 
                );
    $the_query = new WP_Query($args);
    if( $the_query->have_posts() ) :
        while( $the_query->have_posts() ): $the_query->the_post(); ?>

            <h2><a href="<?php echo esc_url( post_permalink() ); ?>"><?php the_title();?></a></h2>

        <?php endwhile;
        wp_reset_postdata();
    endif;

    die();
}
```

Comment: sorry, still get all the posts... I doubled check and the cat id is correct... What can couse to it?

Comment: In your post type init code, i can see that you are trying to register the taxonomy 'category' for article. 'category is default reserved taxonomy, change that so some other taxonomy.

Comment: can you login to your backend and show the url for the category id of 78 ( one  you want to exclude)

Comment: found the error.. the taxonomy is not category, it is audience. Your code is correct. Thank you!!!

Comment: Glad i could help. Cheers !!