# category__not_in in index.php of Woocommerce template not working

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product, custom-taxonomy

I'm new to PHP and WordPress so my question could easily be silly. Although I have found others with similar questions.

On my main page (index.php) I would like to exclude products of a certain category. I found that it should be possible to use category__not_in as a parameter passed to the $args var. but this option doesn't work. When I change other values in the $args var. they are applied. I.e. if I change the post_per_page it is visible immediately. I use the code below and only want to exclude category 28 (could be more in the future). I tried the solutions mentioned in [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36178150/wordpress-category-not-in-not-working), but no success. A

I was wondering if anyone could point me in the right direction. Thanks

```
<section id="content">
<div class="container woocommerce">

    <?php
    remove_action( 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop_item_title', 'woocommerce_template_loop_product_thumbnail', 10 );

    global $woocommerce_loop, $woocommerce;
    $meta_query = $woocommerce->query->get_meta_query();
    $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'product',
        'post_status' => 'publish',     
        'category__not_in' => array( 28 ),
        'ignore_sticky_posts'   => 1,
        'post__not_in' => $slider_arr,
        'posts_per_page' => 9, 
        'paged' => ( get_query_var('paged') ? get_query_var('paged') : 1),

    );  

    $products = new WP_Query( $args );
    //query_posts( $args );

        if ( $products->have_posts() ) : $x = 0; ?>

            <div id="posts_cont">

                <?php while ( $products->have_posts() ) : $products->the_post(); ?>         
                    <?php woocommerce_get_template_part( 'content', 'product-home' ); ?>
                    <?php if ($x == 2) { echo '<div class="home_small_box clear"></div>'; $x = -1; } ?>

                <?php $x++; endwhile; // end of the loop. ?>

            </div><!--//posts_cont-->
        <?php //woocommerce_product_loop_end(); ?>

        <div class="load_more_cont">
            <div align="center"><div class="load_more_text">
            <?php
            ob_start();
            //next_posts_link('<img src="' . get_bloginfo('stylesheet_directory') . '/images/loading-button.png" />');
            next_posts_link('LOAD MORE PRODUCT');
            $buffer = ob_get_contents();
            ob_end_clean();
            if(!empty($buffer)) echo $buffer;
            ?>
            </div></div>
        </div><!--//load_more_cont-->                   
        <?php
        global $wp_query;
        //echo '**' . $wp_query->max_num_pages . '**';  
        $max_pages = $wp_query->max_num_pages;
        ?>          
        <div id="max_pages_id" style="display: none;"><?php echo ceil($wp_query->found_posts / 9); //echo $max_pages-1; ?></div>                    

    <?php endif;
    //wp_reset_query();
    wp_reset_postdata();    

?>              
    <div class="clear"></div>

</div><!--//container-->
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> **`category__not_in`** only work with WordPress categories, but not for WC Product categories

There are some mistakes in your code like:

- Product categories is **a custom taxonomy**, so you need to use a [**Tax Query**](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Taxonomy_Parameters) instead.
- Since Woocommerce 3 `woocommerce_get_template_part()` is deprecated and replaced by `wc_get_template_part()`
- `$meta_query` should be used in your query…
- `$slider_arr` is not defined ***(so I have comment it)***

So try this instead:

```
<section id="content">
<div class="container woocommerce">

    <?php
    remove_action( 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop_item_title', 'woocommerce_template_loop_product_thumbnail', 10 );

    global $woocommerce_loop;

    $products = new WP_Query( array(
        'post_type'     => 'product',
        'post_status'   => 'publish',
        'tax_query'     => array( array(
            'taxonomy'  => 'product_cat',
            'field'     => 'term_id',
            'terms'     => array( 16 ),
            'operator'  => 'NOT IN',
        ) ),
        'meta_query'    => WC()->query->get_meta_query(),
        // 'post__not_in' => $slider_arr,
        'ignore_sticky_posts' => 1,
        'posts_per_page'      => 9,
        'paged' => ( get_query_var('paged') ? get_query_var('paged') : 1),

    ) );

    if ( $products->have_posts() ) : $x = 0; ?>

        <div id="posts_cont">

            <?php while ( $products->have_posts() ) : $products->the_post(); ?>
                <?php wc_get_template_part( 'content', 'product-home' ); ?>
                <?php if ($x == 2) { echo '<div class="home_small_box clear"></div>'; $x = -1; } ?>

            <?php $x++; endwhile; // end of the loop. ?>

        </div><!--//posts_cont-->
        <?php //woocommerce_product_loop_end(); ?>

        <div class="load_more_cont">
        <div align="center"><div class="load_more_text">
        <?php
        ob_start();
        //next_posts_link('<img src="' . get_bloginfo('stylesheet_directory') . '/images/loading-button.png" />');
        next_posts_link('LOAD MORE PRODUCT');
        $buffer = ob_get_contents();
        ob_end_clean();
        if(!empty($buffer)) echo $buffer;
        ?>
        </div></div>
        </div><!--//load_more_cont-->
        <?php
        global $wp_query;
        //echo '**' . $wp_query->max_num_pages . '**';
        $max_pages = $wp_query->max_num_pages;
        ?>
        <div id="max_pages_id" style="display: none;"><?php echo ceil($wp_query->found_posts / 9); //echo $max_pages-1; ?></div>

    <?php endif;
    //wp_reset_query();
    wp_reset_postdata();   

?>              
    <div class="clear"></div>

</div><!--//container-->
```

**Note:** I suppose that `'product-home'` is a custom  product template so I have test the code with default `'product'` instead, to make it work, **and the code works with it.**

Comment: Thx @LoicTheAztec. It is not my code. I try to alter an existing template which is like this. $slider_arr is and global var I supposed. Defined somewhere else. But the main thing which got me triggered is that you say it should be product_cat. I'm going to try that out. Sounds logical. Thx. I get back to this.

Comment: @Stephan If you search for WP_Query regarding Woocommerce product categories, you will see that they all use a **tax query** or the "taxonomy" parameter with "product_cat" …

Comment: Is was indeed the product_cat. I just had to the tax_query syntax. Although you advised to change other things too, I just left it like this. It is working fine now. Thx for the help

Comment: The solution should use `WC_Product_Query()` or `wc_get_products()` instead of `WP_Query()`. [Here's a post explaining why and how](https://cfxdesign.com/create-a-custom-woocommerce-product-loop-the-right-way/).

Comment: @cfx As the author is using a `WP_Query`, my answer here is just solving the Op's problem. I know very well `WC_Product_Query` and I use it. For your own reference [that is the official documentation link](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/wiki/wc_get_products-and-WC_Product_Query)... So **NO** this answer **should not** use a `WC_Product_Query` as it's not the problem here.